# How to declare the interface section for a procedure argument, which in turn references to a user-derived type of the same module?

Tags: types, interface, module, fortran

As the following code sample shows, `person_list` is a user-derived type and contains a type-bound procedure `compare_persons`. I would like `compare_persons` to be able to accept a certain group of `compareFunc` as one of its arguments, and therefore declare the interface section for `compareFunc`. Note the first argument of `compareFunc` is of type `person_list`. (As you might tell, `person_list` is like `TStringList` in Delphi's VCL.)

The compilation cannot proceed. The error messages are:

```
[root@localhost new]# ifort -c lib1.f90 
lib1.f90(26): error #6457: This derived type name has not been declared.   [PERSON_LIST]
                    TYPE(person_list) :: persons    !   error #6457: This derived type name has not been declared.   [PERSON_LIST]
-------------------------^
lib1.f90(23): error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [PERSONS]
                FUNCTION compareFunc(persons, index1, index2)    !   error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [PERSONS] 
-------------------------------------^
compilation aborted for lib1.f90 (code 1)
```

The error messages seem to indicate a circular reference between modules? I am therefore wondering how to declare the interface section for a procedure argument, which in turn references to a user-derived type of the same module? Any insights will be appreciated!

PS: The reason to try this module is the preference of OO programing style. The reason to try fortran is a big code base.

PS: The compiler is Intel Fortran Compiler, and the version is as the follows:

```
[root@localhost new]# ifort --version
ifort (IFORT) 12.1.0 20111011
Copyright (C) 1985-2011 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

## The code sample is:

```
MODULE lib1

    TYPE person_list

    CONTAINS
        PROCEDURE, PASS :: compare_persons

    END TYPE

CONTAINS

    FUNCTION compare_persons(this, index1, index2, compareFunc)

        IMPLICIT NONE

        INTEGER :: compare_persons
        CLASS(person_list) :: this
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: index1
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: index2

        INTERFACE
            FUNCTION compareFunc(persons, index1, index2)    !   error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [PERSONS] 
                IMPLICIT NONE
                INTEGER :: compareFunc
                TYPE(person_list) :: persons    !   error #6457: This derived type name has not been declared.   [PERSON_LIST]
                INTEGER :: index1
                INTEGER :: index2
            END FUNCTION compareFunc
        END INTERFACE

        compare_persons = compareFunc(this, index1, index2)

    END FUNCTION compare_persons

END MODULE lib1
```

## `tpg2114` figures out the solution!

```
MODULE lib1

    TYPE person_list

    CONTAINS
        PROCEDURE, PASS :: compare_persons

    END TYPE

    INTERFACE
        FUNCTION CompareFuncInterface(persons, index1, index2)  
            IMPORT person_list
            IMPLICIT NONE
            INTEGER :: CompareFuncInterface
            TYPE(person_list), INTENT(IN) :: persons    
            INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: index1
            INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: index2
        END FUNCTION CompareFuncInterface
    END INTERFACE

CONTAINS

    FUNCTION compare_persons(this, index1, index2, compareFunc)

        IMPLICIT NONE

        INTEGER :: compare_persons
        CLASS(person_list), INTENT(IN) :: this
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: index1
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: index2
        PROCEDURE (CompareFuncInterface) :: compareFunc

        compare_persons = compareFunc(this, index1, index2)

    END FUNCTION compare_persons

END MODULE lib1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

```
MODULE lib1

   TYPE :: persons
   CONTAINS
      PROCEDURE, PASS :: compare_persons
   END TYPE persons

   INTERFACE
      INTEGER FUNCTION compareFunc_interface(personsIn, index1, index2)
         IMPORT persons
         IMPLICIT NONE
         TYPE(persons), INTENT(IN) :: personsIn
         INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: index1
         INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: index2 
      END FUNCTION compareFunc_interface
   END INTERFACE


CONTAINS 
   FUNCTION compare_persons(this, index1, index2, compareFunc)
      IMPLICIT NONE

      INTEGER :: compare_persons
      CLASS(persons) :: this
      INTEGER :: index1
      INTEGER :: index2
      PROCEDURE(compareFunc_interface) :: compareFunc
   END FUNCTION compare_persons
END MODULE lib1
```

From the 2003 standard, the `IMPORT` statement brings a definition from the host scoping unit to the local scoping unit. If you were using something from a different module, the `INTERFACE` would need a `USE` statement. But since you are importing from the higher up scoping unit, you use `IMPORT` and a list of the things you would like to bring into that scope

**Edit**

Also note, I added `PASS` to the declaration of the type-bound procedure. Although not required (because this is the default action), I prefer to always put `PASS` or `NOPASS` so that the intention is always explicit. This helps both the programmer (making sure they do what they think they are doing) and anybody who reads the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful help! (I am sorry for the bad variables initially! Thank you for your patience very much!) I am wondering would you mind providing a test-driver program to call `person_list%compare_persons`? Just returning a constant value  in the real compareFunc will be fine!

Comment: That I will not do. But, if you need an example on how to call type-bound procedures, check out: http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Object-oriented+programming