# Passing subroutine names from external classes in Fortran

Tags: class, oop, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

In [How to pass subroutine names as arguments in Fortran classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833685/how-to-pass-subroutine-names-as-arguments-in-fortran-classes) we learned how to pass subroutine names as arguments INSIDE Fortran classes. But how do we pass subroutine names from an OUTSIDE class?

The ensuing code produces compilation errors for two distinct attempts using GNU Fortran (GCC) 5.1.0:

```
gfortran  -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Og -pedantic -fcheck=bounds -fmax-errors=5 casey.f08 
casey.f08:42:37:

         call selector ( ints % square, x , y )
                                     1
Error: Expected argument list at (1)
casey.f08:43:24:

         call selector ( ints % double ( x, y ), x , y )
                        1
Error: ‘double’ at (1) should be a FUNCTION
```

The goal is for the routine `selector` to employ different computational paths: one to square a number, another to double it. The first compilation error suggests adding an argument list. The naive remedy for this produces the second error.

An MWE follows. Programming by permutation has produced many variants; hopefully this version can be remedied easily.

```
module myModule

    implicit none

    type     :: intermediates
        real :: z
    contains
        private
        procedure, nopass, public :: square => square_sub
        procedure, nopass, public :: double => double_sub
    end type intermediates

    private :: square_sub
    private :: double_sub

contains

    subroutine square_sub ( x, y )
        real, intent ( in )  :: x
        real, intent ( out ) :: y
            y = x ** 2
    end subroutine square_sub

    subroutine double_sub ( x, y )
        real, intent ( in )  :: x
        real, intent ( out ) :: y
            y = x * 2
    end subroutine double_sub

end module myModule


program casey

    use myModule
    implicit none

    real :: x = 10.0, y
    type ( intermediates ) :: ints
        call selector ( ints % square, x , y )
        call selector ( ints % double ( x, y ), x , y )

contains

    subroutine selector ( sub, x, y )

        interface mySub
            subroutine sub ( x, y )
                real, intent ( in )  :: x
                real, intent ( out ) :: y
            end subroutine sub
        end interface mySub

        real, intent ( in )  :: x
        real, intent ( out ) :: y

            call sub ( x, y )
            print *, 'x = ', x, ', y = ', y

    end subroutine selector

end program casey
```

Comment: I think there should be another question to point you towards.  Instead in the short term, `ints%square` is not a procedure but a binding name.  This may be enough for your continued searching.

Comment: Have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318816/passing-type-bound-procedures-as-arguments-in-fortran-90  You refer to actions "inside" and "outside" classes (which are called derived types in Fortran) - derived types in Fortran don't have executable actions inside them.  Types have bindings and procedure pointer components, those bindings and components then refer to procedures that are always outside the scope of the derived type definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to place the selector procedure inside the class. In the example above, `subroutine selector` is inside the `program`. Below `subroutine local_selector` is a `procedure` within the type `mySubs`.

```
module mySubs

    implicit none

    type :: myClass
    contains
        procedure, nopass, public :: square
        procedure, nopass, public :: double
        procedure, nopass, public :: local_selector
    end type myClass

contains

    subroutine square ( x, y )
        real, intent ( in )  :: x
        real, intent ( out ) :: y
            y = x ** 2
            print *, 'x = ', x, '; x ** 2 = ', y
    end subroutine square

    subroutine double ( x, y )
        real, intent ( in )  :: x
        real, intent ( out ) :: y
            y = x * 2
            print *, 'x = ', x, '; 2 x = ', y
    end subroutine double

    subroutine local_selector ( sub, x, y )

        interface mySub
            subroutine sub ( x, y )
                real, intent ( in )  :: x
                real, intent ( out ) :: y
            end subroutine sub
        end interface mySub

        real, intent ( in )  :: x
        real, intent ( out ) :: y

            call sub ( x, y )

    end subroutine local_selector

end module mySubs

program fixed

    use mySubs
    implicit none

    real :: x = 10.0, y

    type ( myClass ) :: thisClass

        call thisClass % local_selector ( square, x , y )
        call thisClass % local_selector ( double, x , y )

end program fixed
```